# How to sync OneDrive even when I'm signed-out from the computer?

Tags: windows, sync, onedrive, microsoft-onedrive

I work on a server computer and have setup OneDrive. Sync is working fine.

The folder into which the files get synced is shared on the network.

When I sign-out from my computer, the OneDrive sync doesn't work. How to let OneDrive sync even when I'm signed-out from the computer?

Comment: Start OneDrive as a service, of simply don't log off, just lock the screen.

Comment: "How to let OneDrive sync even when I'm signed-out from the computer?" - You don't;  If you are logged out of your machine, applications are not even running under that user, you would have to only lock the machine or switch to a different user to keep OneDrive running.

Comment: @Aganju - Don't log off isn't a solution for me. The start as service may be the solution so please can you expand bit more on how to do this please?

Comment: In my option, I do not think OneDrive will works after you signing out from computer. When the computer is logged off, non-system programs will be ended.

Comment: @Emily - Maybe this is the solution https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-stop-and-start-onedrive-syncing-my-simple/d39d3951-5ada-4e59-b4b2-586dd7fdfda2